# Como inverter série de condições negadas sem afetar a lógica?

Tags: java, android, operadores, condição

Alguém poderia me explicar porque isso acontece? Minha apk só funciona direito se eu colocar negação e fazer algo:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText nome, teste, cpf;
    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editnome);
        teste = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcopia);
        cpf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcpf);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!nome.getText().toString().trim().equals("") && !teste.getText().toString().trim().equals("") && !cpf.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não vazio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vazio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Agora se eu colocar dessa forma nao funciona por que?:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (nome.getText().toString().trim().equals("") && teste.getText().toString().trim().equals("") && cpf.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vazio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não vazio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Porque faltou inverter o operador relacional de `&&` para `||`.

No primeiro você quer que ambos sejam não vazios. Então verifica cada um se não é vazio, e aplica o `&&` para garantir que os dois operandos sejam como deseja. O operador de [`AND`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) exige que ambos sejam verdadeiros.

No segundo verifica se ambos são vazios. Mas não é o que deseja, basta um dele ser vazio para considerar que há alguma coisa vazia. Então precisa do operador de [`OR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) que exige apenas que um dos operandos seja verdadeiro.

**Sempre que inverter os operadores das expressões lógicas que compõem uma expressão relacional o operador relacional tem que ser invertido também, para preservar a verdade matemática**.

Assim funciona como o esperado:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(nome.getText().toString().trim().equals("") || teste.getText().toString().trim().equals("") || cpf.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Vazio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Não vazio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
});
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Operator/Inversion.java).

Na verdade duvido que precise desse `toString()` e acho que o resto poderia ser substituído por [`isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--).

Comment: Eu ia complementar a minha com a parte do `||`, agora não preciso mais

Comment: Depende ele considera um espaço vazio como algo ali dentro? a questão do isEmpty...

Comment: @gonz acho que não, aí teria que usar o `trim()` mesmo. Precisa ver se o dado precisa de `trim()`.

Answer (score 6):

São lógicas opostas. Tente colocar em português que fica mais claro. Por exemplo, a primeira versão diz:

```
Se NADA ESTÁ VAZIO:
    Considera preenchido
    // Garantido que TODOS estejam PREENCHIDOS
Senão:
    Considera vazio
    // Se houver PELO MENOS UM VAZIO
```

Já a segunda versão diz:

```
Se TUDO ESTÁ VAZIO:
    Considera vazio
    // Somente se TODOS estiverem VAZIOS
Senão:
    Considera preenchido
    // Pelo menos um preenchido, mas pode haver algum vazio
```